# Firebase logged in user with expired Auth ID token

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

In my released Flutter app using Firebase, I've noticed that Firebase snapshot listeners sometimes get "stuck" and show outdated data when the app is resumed after being in the background for an extended period (5-10 hours). In some cases, restarting the app fixed the issue, and in others, it resolved itself after a few seconds.

From my crash reports, I've identified the issue as being tied to an invalid/expired Firebase Auth ID token, leading to a 'Permission Denied' error. Interestingly, my user auth listener didn't trigger, so the user remained logged in despite the expired token. This happened even though the internet connection was active.

This behavior is inconsistent and challenging to replicate for a minimal example. I'm looking for guidance on how to effectively handle Firebase Auth ID token expiration, especially while a user remains logged in and snapshot listeners are active in a Flutter app. What is the recommended approach for this situation?

```
_authStateSubscription =
    FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((user) {
  if (user == null) {
    set(RouteState.login()); //did not fire when auth id token expired
  }
});
```

Comment: ID tokens *should* be auto-refreshed by the SDKs **before** the listeners are reattached when the app resumes, but it sounds like that is not happening here. What platform is this on? And is there any chance you can enable all debug logging and see if you can grab the output from that?

Comment: Thank you for your response. This issue is observed on Android; I haven't yet tested on iOS for extended periods. For enabling debug logging, I'm unsure how to do it on a release build. Errors are collected from Crashlytics through an error handler on a snapshot listener.
I haven't encountered this issue in debug builds, likely due to debug builds often failing to resume after long background periods, resulting in a persistent white screen and requiring an app restart. This doesn't happen in release builds. How can I enable all debug logging on my local release build? @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: That only recently became possible for Firestore in Flutter through https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FirebaseFirestore/setLoggingEnabled.html. If the output of just the Firestore SDK doesn't show enough detail, you'd might need to check if something similar exists in the Auth SDK, as it's likely some interaction between those two SDKs.

Comment: I have updated to the latest version of cloud_firestore and firebase_auth and I added 'await FirebaseFirestore.setLoggingEnabled(true)', but I could not find any equivalent function yet in firebase_auth. I'll wait for the error to repeat and I'll inspect the logs and report back here. If there is a way to add this type of logging for firebase_auth that I missed please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, fingers crossed the debug output of Firestore gives us enough to go on, as. also don't immediately recall how to enable Auth logging on Android: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.

Comment: Hi does my posted answer help ? If not then we can solve further.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Facing issue where all long-lived snapshots freeze every other day on my device, while on-demand ones operate normally. I'm finding it tough to extract useful data from logcat, as this issue doesn't output clear errors. Here's a video with details (https://youtube.com/shorts/mNMolDACop0?feature=share) that illustrates the problem: the 'about me' text on the profile screen updates correctly (on demand snapshot), yet the same field in the edit profile screen is stuck with outdated data (long lived snapshot). Any advice where to go from here? is Firebase team looking into this?

Comment: @RohitKharche Thank you for your answer. The source of the problem seems to be in the inner workings of snapshot listeners and not the token itself. The comments of FrankvanPuffelen have the details.

Comment: Can you share the logcat output from the Firestore SDK around the moment the restore happens and the write fails. I expect we'll see an error about security rules failing for the write, but would like to see what it says right before that about restoring the user credentials. --- It'd also help to see the [minimal code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the listener of which we then see that logging output.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen there is no write error, writes work correctly and new snapshot listeners do pickup the changes. The problem is that all pre-existing snapshot listeners no longer receive any updates so remain stuck with stale data. The current solution is to restart the app but my users would not know this. Is there a place I can communicate this issue with you outside of this comment section? I believe this is a critical issue for Firebase and I have delayed the marketing campaign for my app since this is not a rare occurrence, it happens every other day.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen To create a demonstrator I'd create a Firebase/Flutter app with login and a persist page with a document int incrementor and a snapshot listener below it that prints out the value, this would require someone to install the app and keep checking it over days until the listener stop updating in response to writes. This is inefficient, I think maybe better to force refresh the token every 500ms (I might hit quota limit) to accelerate error occurrence, but it might also involve switching from the background. However I'm not sure since I don't know the inner workings of Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**getIdTokenResult method**](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/getIdTokenResult.html) this will do the following :

```js
Future<IdTokenResult> getIdTokenResult(
[bool forceRefresh = false]
)
```

- Returns an IdTokenResult containing the users JSON Web Token (JWT) and other metadata.
- Returns the current token if it has not expired. Otherwise, this will refresh the token and return a new one.
- If forceRefresh is true, the token returned will be refreshed regardless of token expiration.

**OR**

You can use [**idTokenChanges() listener**](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/start#idtokenchanges) to listen to the change in the current user's token :

```js
FirebaseAuth.instance.idTokenChanges().listen((User? user) {
  if (user != null && user.uid != null) {
    // The user is still signed in.
    // Refresh the ID token if it has expired.
    user.getIdTokenResult(true).then((token) {
        // The ID token has been refreshed.
    });
  } else {
    // The user is not signed in.
    // Sign the user in.
  });
```

It will be listening on following :

- Right after the listener has been registered.
- When a user is signed in.
- When the current user is signed out.
- When there is a change in the current user's token.

But sometimes using just `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.reload()` does the trick for me many times for more about this you can find this [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/reload.html).

##### Reference :

1. [**Get Started with Firebase Authentication on Flutter**](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/start)
2. [**firebase_auth library**](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/firebase_auth-library.html)